# Tooltip z-index displaying underneath other elements

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, tooltip

So I currently have a tool tip displaying when hovering over some navigation elements however while the tool tip does display over the element the mouse is hovering over it displays underneath all the other elements.(Sorry if that's not clear, it's a nav bar... so the tool tip of link 1 has the text of link 2 over the top making it unreadable ) I've tried changing the z-index on the different elements (as suggested in a previous answer) and I've either tried changing it the standard bootstrap method of "data-toggle='tooltip'" but this method doesn't seem to render the html properly (even when using razer @Html.Raw()).

```
<li class="nav-item tooltip">
<a class="nav-link active" href="#"><i class="fal fa-file-alt"></i>  <span>INVOICES</span></a>
<span class="tooltiptext" data-placement="top">@Html.Raw(UIMessages.TTSignUp)</span>
</li>

<li class="nav-item tooltip">
<a class="nav-link active" href="#"><i class="fal fa-pound-sign"></i><span>EXPENSES</span></a>
<span class="tooltiptext">@Html.Raw(UIMessages.TTSignUp)</span>
</li>

<li class="nav-item tooltip">
<a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tooltip" title="@Html.Raw(UIMessages.TTSignUp)" href="#"><i class="fal fa-pound-sign"></i><span>PENSION</span></a>
<span class="tooltiptext">@Html.Raw(UIMessages.TTSignUp)</span>
</li>
```

My css / scss...

```
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 1 !important;


}


.toptip span {
    z-index: 9999999;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: $TrigDarkBlue;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    /* Position the tooltip */
    position: absolute;

    top: -5px;
    left: 5%;

    a {
        color: $TrigBlue;
    }
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 100%;
    margin-top: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent $TrigDarkBlue transparent transparent;
    z-index: 9999
}
```

So I thought it would be as simple as just changing the z-index of the '.tooltiptext' but clearly not. Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: where you want tooltip position?

Comment: To the ride or below... the position is fine to be honest it's more the stack ordering that's the issue

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code... I haved add `bottom: -38px;` on `.tooltip .tooltiptext` class

```css
    .tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 1 !important;


}


.toptip span {
    z-index: 9999999;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: red;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -38px;
    left: 0;

    a {
        color: $TrigBlue;
    }
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 100%;
    margin-top: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent $TrigDarkBlue transparent transparent;
    z-index: 9999
}
```

```html
        <li class="nav-item tooltip">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="#"><i class="fal fa-file-alt"></i>  <span>INVOICES</span></a>
                <span class="tooltiptext" data-placement="top">@Html.Raw(UIMessages.TTSignUp)</span>
                </li>
                
                <li class="nav-item tooltip">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="#"><i class="fal fa-pound-sign"></i><span>EXPENSES</span></a>
                <span class="tooltiptext">@Html.Raw(UIMessages.TTSignUp)</span>
                </li>
                
                <li class="nav-item tooltip">
                <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tooltip" title="@Html.Raw(UIMessages.TTSignUp)" href="#"><i class="fal fa-pound-sign"></i><span>PENSION</span></a>
                <span class="tooltiptext">@Html.Raw(UIMessages.TTSignUp)</span>
                </li>
```

Comment: Thanks Mohit I appreciate it but it's not really solving the issue of the stack ordering, that's just moving it to appear below. (I know i said to the side or below but I'd rather figure out why the ordering isn't right)

Comment: span has padding so we need to add css on bottom.

Comment: you can also take tool-tip example here : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp